# WCF Service Behavior to add an operation to my services

Tags: wcf, servicebehavior

I'd like to create a service behavior which adds an extra service operation to my service.  This way I can add the behavior to any of my services (existing and future) and my service will all be able to perform this extra service operation. (e.g. ping or returns some other service information)

I'm not sure what to do here to achieve what I want, What I've tried to do so far is to implement a service behavior which tries to modify the service description.  Should I add an endpoint and then specify a new contract on that?

```
public class MyOperationBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
   void IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(
                    ServiceDescription desc, ServiceHostBase host)
    {
       ServiceEndpointCollection sec = svcDesc.Endpoints;
       ServiceEndpoint se = new ServiceEndpoint()
       {
            se.Address = "DoMyOperation";
            se.Binding = "basicHttpBinding";
            se.Contract = MyCustomContract;           
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by extra operation? Should it be additional service method?

Comment: @k0stya yes, an extra service operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what I was looking for in this article on [Dynamically adding methods to a WCF service](http://zamd.net/2010/02/05/adding-dynamic-methods-to-a-wcf-service/) without having to add it to each service contract.

But I also believe using WS-Discovery is a much better way of achieving what I want: exposing information about a service without having to touch the service contracts

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of using services is that you are exposing a well-defined and fairly static set of operations to your consumers.

I'm not sure how being able to dynamically add service operations at runtime would benefit your consumers.

I would suggest that if you need to change your service contract on a per-consumer basis then it may indicate that your service composition is probably incorrect for the needs of your consumers.

Apologies this does not answer your question directly, and appreciate that re-work on the scale suggested may be outside current development scope.

Comment: maybe my question is wrong and I'm going about this the wrong way.  IMetadataExchange is a behavior that exposes information about the service on an endpoint, I'm trying to do something similar. *edit* sorry I meant servicemetadatabehavior

Comment: Sorry not sure what you are getting at here. It sounds as if you want to add an endpoint operation, but the standard way of doing this is to modify your service contract.